# What is the cause of a shower diverter valve becoming stuck?

Tags: shower

When I tried to shower today, when I pulled the shower diverter, it didn't divert most of the water to the shower (most of the water kept coming out of the faucet). I tried to push the diverter back down with the water running, and it became stuck. Now I can't pull or push it.

Was it because I tried to push it back that it got stuck?

Comment: It sounds like it may have broken internally. Time for a new one.

Comment: I second and upvote Dave Tweed's commend. Just get a new one. (I have had same problem - it's just broken)

Answer (score 2):

I got it replaced with a new one and it works perfectly. Even after detaching it, the diverter didn't move.

Comment: When you replaced it did you see how or why it was broken? Bent shaft? Bad gasket?

Comment: Unfortunately no - I wasn't sure what to inspect.